# Error loading tmLanguage and tmTheme files in Sublime Text 3

Tags: color-scheme, sublimetext3

With Sublime Text 2 I was able to style an output panel with

```
MyOutputView.set_syntax_file("/Path_to/my.tmLanguage")
MyOutputView.settings().set("color_scheme", "/Path_to/my.tmTheme")
```

in the current beta (3047) of Sublime Text 3 two windows pop up with the following messages (they also get printed to the console):

> Error loading syntax file "/Path_to/my.tmLanguage": Unable to open
>   /Path_to/my.tmLanguage

and:

> Error loading colour scheme /Path_to/my.tmTheme: Unable to open
>   /Path_to/my.tmTheme

Is this a bug that I should report, did the API change, did sublime move away from `tm` files?

Comment: try using paths like `"Packages/MyStuff/My.tmLanguage"` and see if that works - I'm not sure if those functions can accept absolute paths...

Comment: I deleted my previous comment, what you suggest actually works! If you make it an answer, I'll accept it! Thanks so much, this has frustrated me for the past hour.

Comment: you're quite welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [ST3 API docs](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html), it seems that most of the paths are relative, either to `Packages` or `Installed Packages`, depending on the class/method you're looking at. Since plugins should be designed for portability between 3 different platforms, and between standard and portable installs, relative paths are a good idea. Try setting your code to:

```py
MyOutputView.set_syntax_file("Packages/MyLang/my.tmLanguage")
MyOutputView.settings().set("color_scheme", "Packages/MyColorScheme/my.tmTheme")
```

and you should be all set.